# Nixos package manager on Ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Would the nixos package manager work on an ubuntu touch device without making the system read-write?

Comment: Do you mean the Nix package manager? NixOS seems to be an entirely different distribution, so it would not run on top of Ubuntu Touch. I don't think trying to use the Nix package manager to install NixOS packages would get you anywhere. 

If you just mean to ask whether there are package managers other than apt that would work without making the system r/w, then yes, that's what click and (hopefully soon) snap packages are for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "[Nix package manager](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_package_manager)" (NixOS is a linux distribution built on top of Nix packages manager).

Nix installs its packages into `/nix` folder which you need to make it writable for user that will perform installations. we call this single-user mode. There is also multi-user mode which allows multiple users to install packages, but setup is a [little more complicated](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ssec-multi-user).

Also Nix community does not provide binaries for ARM architecture so you will need to build Nix and every package from scratch. There was a talk on mailing list to start supporting ARM arch, but conversation is still in progress.

And in case you are interested there is a nice [comparison between Snappy and Nix](http://sandervanderburg.blogspot.de/2015/04/an-evaluation-and-comparison-of-snappy.html) done awhile back. Snappy looks pretty poor choice when you compared to Nix. But maybe I'm just using Nix for too long :)